# Using python to pull values from an application on my computer

Tags: javascript, python, html, http

I have a news application that's on my desktop, and I am wondering if there is a way to pull data from this app directly using python. I will post a picture of what the app looks like.

[image]

Lets say I want to pull the DE GDP results as they change upon news release. Is there any way I can gain access to these values locally, rather than trying to pull it using json or xpath? I tried JSON and got it to pull values, but it takes up to 10 seconds to update, and I want it to update as fast as possible. I figured the fastest way to get the updated values would be to pull them locally on my computer somehow, but I am not very knowledgeable on this sort of thing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can inspect the page and in network section see the url which is being called to render the data, and you can see the response as well.

like i am done it for sample page.
you can see the screenshot.

[click on this link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu31H.png)

Comment: I see.. Would you use python/json for this? Could you possibly provide a code sample for grabbing a piece of data off of this link? I am struggling to code what you mean. https://next.newsimpact.com/NewsWidget/Live

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to use a web service. After all, the app you are showing must be pulling its data from some service. You could use a network sniffer to find out where exactly.

Answer (score 0):

[[image: your site 1]]

seeing the network it says the url which is fetching data is.
https://next.newsimpact.com/NewsWidget/GetNextEvents?offset=-330

and when you open it in new tab.

[image: json data]

so you can easily use this url to fetch the json data with request library in python

some brief code:

pip install requests

import requests

r = requests.get('https://next.newsimpact.com/NewsWidget/GetNextEvents?offset=-330')

print r.json